# Maths symbol that looks like Sputnik

Tags: notation

I'm doing some marking for a year 8 (12 to 13-year-old) scholarship paper and I saw this symbol that looks like the Sputnik probe and I have no idea what it is, does anyone know?

[image: Image of strange symbol]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think it is a typesetting problem with the parentheses.

My best guess at the intended question would be:

$$\left( 2-\frac 12 \right) \left( 2-\frac 23 \right) \left( 2-\frac 34 \right) \left( 2-\frac 45 \right)$$

This seems reasonable given the level of the other questions.